# Tic Tac Toe layout to identify frequency of digits

Tags: python, frequency

I have a list of keys and values and wish to use the image as attached for better visualization. Can anyone recommend where to start in python?

from the image,  1 has a frequency of 3, 3 has a frequency of 2 and etc. The values will be dependent factor of how many rings around the keys.

```
keys=[1, 3, 6, 8, 9]
values=[3, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` and a dictionary comprehension:

```py
keys=[1, 3, 6, 8, 9]
values=[3, 2, 3, 1, 2]
print({key: value for key, value in zip(keys, values)})
```